# How to go to last edit location in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, edit, history, back

How to go to last edit location/s in android studio?

Clicking the back arrow in the toolbar makes you travel within your navigation history.

But I want to travel within my edition history i.e. navigate through the last change/s I made in code.

Eclipse have a back arrow with star on it for this.

[image: this arrow is present in Eclipse for the same]

Comment: Are you looking to undo the changes as you navigate through the edits?  On Windows, ctrl-z is the usual keyboard short cut for that.

Comment: I think there is only the undo function in Android Studio, but it is not for navigating.

Comment: @MichaelVincent not undo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto **Navigate** menu and find **Last Edit Location** option.

Shortcut: **ctrl + Q**

**DONE**

Answer (score 15):

Go to `File` -> `Settings...` -> `Keymap`.

In the search box type "last edit location".

Your default shortcut for *Last Edit Location* should show up (mine is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> on the screenshot below).

You can also change it by double (or right) clicking on it.

[image]

Comment: thanks but isn't there any simple and QUICK solution i.e. at least a short cut

Comment: You can set whatever shortcut you would like here. As you can see on the screenshot, mine is Ctrl + Q. You can just right click on it to change the shortcut.

Comment: Its default values i `Ctrl+Shift+Backspace`

Comment: Made my day! Thanks.
Not only was I able to find this keymap shortcut, but now I know a quick way to find other shortcuts and be 100% certain too.
If I would have downloaded the list of  keymaps, they would not have been specific to my setup and may not have worked.
Much appreciated. 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

I got the short cut

Mac: **Cmd+Shift+Backspace**

Windows/Linux: **Ctrl-Shift-Backspace**

It's working for me

Answer (score 6):

To go to last edit location/s in android studio, Press :

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd><--</kbd>

**Update**

To list the files you navigated to previously, press :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>

To list only files that have been edited, press :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>

What you should have in **Navigate** under **File->Settings->Keymap** :
[image]

Comment: thanks but this don't work, Alt & Back is like UNDO, i want only to navigate, not undo my changes

Answer (score 3):

Go to VCS in menu then Local History then Show History. You will find all your Changes made in Project from beginning or After project Importing. I think you are Searching for this.

[image: Local History Path]

Answer (score 3):

For mac users to go to last edited location use: <kbd>⌘</kbd> +  
<kbd>⌥</kbd>  +  <kbd>←</kbd>  /  <kbd>→</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
Shift + cmd + Delete
```

- I'm using android studio 3.2.3
- MacOS Mojave 10.14

Answer (score 0):

Use `Command + ALT` if you are using external keyboard.

Comment: Windows for MAC

Answer (score 0):

For mac users to go to last edited location use: ⌘ + ⌥  + ←  /